# Most efficient way to update 2D texture on OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-es, glsl, textures

Currently I am working on a application to render frame image from video clip as a 2D texture on a plain mesh surface using OpenGL but I am not sure how to implement this appropriately or efficiently because it has a harsh requirement in process time when updating every frame.

When the application is initialized, there is a default texture image mapped and rendered on the mesh. After the video starts playing, the application shall constantly receive the frame data (unsigned char* pointer) and update mesh texture in every draw call. The size (width and height) of frame image may be different to the mapped default texture image. Besides, what we want is to minimize the cost in binding and unbinding texture in order to improve the efficiency.

Based on some research I have done, FBO looks like a good idea but there is not much relevant samples online that can be very helpful in my case. I really appreciate any suggestion and guidance with my case, it would be better if anyone would share the code in C++ and shader.

Comment: [Buffer Object Streaming](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object_Streaming) with Pixel Buffer Objects is your best bet.

Comment: Is this desktop GL or OpenGL ES?

Comment: ... and if it's ES then is it ES 3? If it's not then how do you feel about vendor-specific solutions?